# Can I use odbc to open files larger than 2 gb? The driver could not update and locked

Tags: odbc

I used odbc with MS access 64-bit dBase driver to open .dbf files larger than 2 GB in SAS. It always gave back an error called "Microsoft ODBC dBase driver could not update, currently locked by user ... on machine ...

Then I tried file smaller than 2 GB, it works well.

Thanks.